# Get a plus score if two conditions are met?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a game and I ran into a problem. The idea is to get a score +1 if two conditions are met. I want to get +1 score if a specific random image is shown and a specific button is clicked if both conditions are met the score should increase by one. This is my code so far.

The code does work and increases the score by one if a specific picture is shown but I need the button click with it as well to work properly.

```
var clicks = 0;  
var myPix = ["faces/angry.png", "faces/happy.png", "faces/normal.png","faces /pur.png","faces/sad.png"];

function choosePic() {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
    document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];
    if ([randomNum]  == 1) {
        clicks++;updateClickCount();
    }
}

function startTimer() {
    setInterval(choosePic, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but I think you should change this  if ([randomNum]  == 1) into  if (randomNum  == 1)

Comment: You need to use a button to do what the `setInterval` is doing ?

Comment: No as you can see i have a array with 5 pictures 1 picture of the 5 is randomly picked. If a specific picture for example 2 is picked in this case normal.png then a specific button should be pressed if those conditions are both met the score should increase by 1.

So to clarify it should have 5 buttons that are linked to the 5 images.

Button 1 => angry.png 
Button 2 => happy.png 
Button 3 => normal.png etc..

Comment: I doubt if your code works. What are you trying to do with `[randomNum] == 1`? That's invalid syntax. What errors do you see in the console.

Comment: I have already changed that to randomNum  == 1 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Add a global variable `myPicture` which holds the index of the actual image. Change the variable `randomNum` to `myPicture` in the function `choosePic`. Delete in the function the condition.
2. Add some buttons with an event `onclick` and an appropriate function to handle the click.

   ```
   <button onclick="clicked(0);">angry</button>
   ```
3. Add the function for the click event.

   ```
   function clicked(index) {
       // this checks the actual picture index with the index of the button
       if (myPicture === index) {
           clicks++;
           updateClickCount();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add the function for the display of the count of the clicks

   ```
   function updateClickCount() {
       document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = clicks;
   }
   ```
5. Start the interval

   ```
   startTimer();
   ```

Here the working code without images:

```js
var clicks = 0,
    myPix = ["faces/angry.png", "faces/happy.png", "faces/normal.png", "faces /pur.png", "faces/sad.png"],
    myPicture;

function choosePic() {
    myPicture = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
    document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[myPicture];
    // only to the see the picture name
    document.getElementById("myPicture").alt = myPix[myPicture];
}

function startTimer() {
    setInterval(choosePic, 1000);
}

function clicked(index) {
    if (myPicture === index) {
        clicks++;
        updateClickCount();
    }
}

function updateClickCount() {
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = clicks;
}

startTimer();
```

```html
<img id="myPicture" width="100" height="50"/><br />
<button onclick="clicked(0);">angry</button>
<button onclick="clicked(1);">happy</button>
<button onclick="clicked(2);">normal</button>
<button onclick="clicked(3);">pur</button>
<button onclick="clicked(4);">sad</button><br />
Count: <span id="count">0</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nina that was exactly what i was looking for! :)